# Fetching the last updated data per item in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am working on stock related project.while searching item stock according particular date ,it is showing every item record history.Like my database "details" is below,

[image: details table]

i made one search query,but it is showing record history item ,
my query is:

```
select details.itemname, details.total from details 
inner join ( select DISTINCT itemname, max(date) as MaxDate 
from details group by itemname ) tm on details.itemname = tm.itemname 
and  details.date <='2016-09-28'
```

But result should come like this:

[image]

Comment: That query is getting everything from details that was in details before today. I haven't worked out the best query yet, but the one in your inner join is much closer to what you would want than the full query is.

Answer (score 0):

Is this maybe what you're looking for?

```
select details.itemname, details.total
from details
order by details.date desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.But this query is showing only last item entry.Like above case it is showing only "Pen" record which is 150.But not showing CFL and BULB data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of you problem.

```
select details.itemname, details.total from details 
    inner join 
    ( select DISTINCT itemname, id, max(date) as MaxDate 
    from details GROUP by details.itemname ) tm
    on (details.itemname = tm.itemname and details.date = tm.MaxDate)
    and details.date <='9/28/2016'
```

The problem was feature dependency. Between Max() and GROUP BY.